# not all code paths return a value error for my quickselect method

Tags: c#

below code is my quickselect (something very similar to quicksort except that it returns nth item in the sorted array, not the whole sorted array) method. the input is array of strings(words), and I have to return the word of nth index if the given words are sorted.

```
    static string QuickSelect(string[] lst, int index) {
        if (lst.Length == 1)
        {
            Console.Write(lst[0]);
            return lst[0];
        }

        else
        {
            int pivot = _r.Next(lst.Length); // pick a pivot by random number generator
            bool[] isDecre = new bool[lst.Length];
            string[] WordLeft, WordRight;
            int nLeft = 0, nRight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Length; i++) // compare values to pivot
            {
                if (i == pivot) continue;
                if (WordCompare(lst[pivot], lst[i]))
                {
                    nRight++;
                    isDecre[i] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    nLeft++;
                    isDecre[i] = true;
                }
            }


            if (nLeft == index) // pivot was the (index)th item in the list
                return lst[pivot];

            else
            {

                WordLeft = new string[nLeft];
                WordRight = new string[nRight];
                int l = 0, r = 0;
                // divide list by saved comparison result
                for (int i = 0; i < lst.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == pivot) continue;
                    if (isDecre[i])
                    {
                        WordLeft[l] = lst[i];
                        l++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WordRight[r] = lst[i];
                        r++;
                    }
                }

                if (nLeft > index)
                    return QuickSelect(WordLeft, index);
                else if (nLeft < index)
                    return QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is that this code won't run, throwing "not all code paths return a value" error. I think it has to do with this part:

```
if (nLeft == index) // pivot was the (index)th item in the list
    return lst[pivot];
// build left and right word lists
 ...
if (nLeft > index)
    return QuickSelect(WordLeft, index);
else if (nLeft < index)
    return QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1);
```

if I put some 'else' after above 'else if', the error goes away. But I don't want to build left and right word lists when the pivot was the nth index string. In fact I think this non-value-returning-path-detected is kinda nonsense. is there any workaround?

Comment: If `nLeft == index` you don't return a value, simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no workaround.

You have to return value **or** throw an exception (which won't be handled in that method) in all paths in the method.

EDIT:

On the other hand, your conditions:

```
if (nLeft == index) // pivot was the (index)th item in the list
    return lst[pivot];
// build left and right word lists
 ...
if (nLeft > index)
    return QuickSelect(WordLeft, index);
else if (nLeft < index)
    return QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1);
```

could be changed to this:

```
if (nLeft == index) // pivot was the (index)th item in the list
    return lst[pivot];
// build left and right word lists
 ...
if (nLeft > index)
    return QuickSelect(WordLeft, index);
return QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1);
```

Comment: You can even drop the the else as the contents of the if are a return.

Comment: Perfectly Solved. btw I prefer having "else" keywords, wouldn't that give a slight improve in readability? or is there some speed penalties?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I know. I just have to wait a while to accept an answer. Thanks for your quick advice.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `return (nLeft > index) ? QuickSelect(WordLeft, index) : QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

`if (nLeft > index)

     return QuickSelect(WordLeft, index);

       else if (nLeft < index)

         return QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1);

       else //nLeft== index

           return "something";`

if both the condition fail then still u need to return some value, which you can further handle that case based on return value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would only return the value if the conditions specified were true. Since you have specified three conditions, the method will only return a value when one of these conditions become true but you'll receive an error in this case as the application will not know what to do if both three conditions become false. There will be no value to return since you haven't specified what will be done when these conditions become false, and that's why you receive an error as a bool can be `true` or `false`

```
if (nLeft == index) //Continue if the condition becomes true
    return lst[pivot]; //Return a value
 ...
if (nLeft > index) //Continue if the condition becomes true
    return QuickSelect(WordLeft, index); //Return a value
else if (nLeft < index) //Continue if the condition becomes true
    return QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1); //Return a value
```

You should have added a line to this method which simply tells the application to return another value if these conditions become false (The other possibility for a `bool`)

**Example**

```
if (nLeft == index) //Continue if the condition becomes true
    return lst[pivot]; //Return a value
 ...
if (nLeft > index) //Continue if the condition becomes true
    return QuickSelect(WordLeft, index); //Return a value
else if (nLeft < index) //Continue if the condition becomes true
    return QuickSelect(WordRight, index - nLeft - 1); //Return a value
else //Continue if these conditions become false
    return /* value */; //Return a value
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)